# Is there a simple way to send a packet over a raw socket using Ruby's Socket class?

Tags: ruby, sockets, translation

I'm presently trying to write something in Ruby which will send data over a raw socket. It may be in part due to a somewhat shaky understanding of sockets, but I feel as though the resources are almost-but-not-quite there.

In particular, I'm trying to convert the following Python code (in case it helps):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from socket import socket, AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW
s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)
s.bind(("lo", 0))

geonet_frame = "\x00\x1f\xc6\x51\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\xc6
\x51\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\xef\x06\x07\x35\x97\x00\x24\x8c\x7a\xdf\x6f\x08
\x00\x45\x00\x00\x3d\xf3\x7f\x40\x00\x40\x11\x30\xc6\x0a\x01\x01\x68\x0a\x01
\x01\x01\x99\x80\x00\x35\x00\x29\x16\xa5\x01\x76\x01\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x01
\x00\x00\x00"

s.send(geonet_frame)
```

In searching the matter, the results I see most often are [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344534/how-can-i-use-raw-sockets-in-ruby), which does not directly provide any workable code examples, and [this explanation](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/90408) which seems to do a lot more than I need and also seems to include a file which I cannot access.

I have tried a few things listed in the [documentation for the Socket class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html), but I can never quite seem to achieve the same results even if I can make it work. For example, I might try:

```
soc = Socket.open(Socket::PF_INET, Socket::SOCK_RAW, Socket::IPPROTO_RAW)
soc.send(mypacket, 0, Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(0, "127.0.0.1"))
```

...and while it will complete, it does not produce the desired result (in this case, it does not create a DOS on TCPDump as denoted [here](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/534010), while the equivalent Python code would).

Is this more complicated in Ruby than I'm expecting? Or am I just missing some magical combination of functions which would allow me to do this?

Update: Here is a picture of a capture of the desired packet.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e4f5.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
require 'socket'

interface = 'lo'         # loopback interface
interface_index = 0x8933 # SIOCGIFINDEX
geonet_frame = "\x00\x1f\xc6\x51\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\xc6\x51\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\x07\xef\x06\x07\x35\x97\x00\x24\x8c\x7a\xdf\x6f\x08\x00\x45\x00\x00\x3d\xf3\x7f\x40\x00\x40\x11\x30\xc6\x0a\x01\x01\x68\x0a\x01\x01\x01\x99\x80\x00\x35\x00\x29\x16\xa5\x01\x76\x01\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00"

socket = Socket.new(Socket::AF_PACKET, Socket::SOCK_RAW, Socket::IPPROTO_RAW)
ifreq = [interface.dup].pack 'a32'
socket.ioctl(interface_index, ifreq)
socket.bind([Socket::AF_PACKET].pack('s') + [Socket::IPPROTO_RAW].pack('n') + ifreq[16..20]+ ("\x00" * 12))

socket.send(geonet_frame, 0)
```

I used `AF_PACKET` because it matched the python example, but you can replace it with `PF_PACKET` if your system doesn't support it.

Replacing the `geonet_frame` variable as Cocoabean suggested also works:

```
geonet_frame = [ 0x00, 0x1f, 0xc6, 0x51, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0xc6, 0x51, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07,0x07, 0x07, 0xef, 0x06, 0x07, 0x35, 0x97, 0x00, 0x24, 0x8c, 0x7a, 0xdf, 0x6f, 0x08, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3d, 0xf3, 0x7f, 0x40, 0x00, 0x40, 0x11, 0x30, 0xc6, 0x0a, 0x01, 0x01, 0x68, 0x0a, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x99, 0x80, 0x00, 0x35, 0x00, 0x29, 0x16, 0xa5, 0x01, 0x76, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00].pack("C*")
```

Tested with ruby 1.9.3p484 on CentOS 6.6. Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Optionally, if you get the chance, I'd like to ask for you to elaborate on what was incorrect and why these changes produced the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it right as far as creating the socket, you just are sending the data in the wrong format. Python sees a series of bytes whereas ruby sees a string of characters. The `pack` method will create a String from the array of bytes.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-pack

Try using this as the value for `mypacket` in your example attempt:

```
    mypacket = [ 0x00, 0x1f, 0xc6, 0x51, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 
0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0xc6, 0x51, 0x07, 
0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0xef, 0x06, 0x07, 0x35, 0x97, 
0x00, 0x24, 0x8c, 0x7a, 0xdf, 0x6f, 0x08, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x3d, 0xf3, 0x7f, 0x40, 0x00, 0x40, 0x11, 0x30, 0xc6, 
0x0a, 0x01, 0x01, 0x68, 0x0a, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x99, 0x80, 
0x00, 0x35, 0x00, 0x29, 0x16, 0xa5, 0x01, 0x76, 0x01, 0x00, 
0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00].pack("C*")
```

[simplest way to send raw Byte-arrays using Ruby's TCPSocket-Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326424/simplest-way-to-send-raw-byte-arrays-using-rubys-tcpsocket-class)

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't produce the correct packet. I will update the question with a picture of a capture of the correct packet. For comparison, here is the result of the one my / your code produces: http://i.imgur.com/76K8bWs.png?1

Comment: I think posting the correct packet would be a huge help.

Comment: The capture of the packet is on the main question in addition to the comment above.